# Easier way than using a switch case to change color

Tags: php, switch-statement, case

[On my website](http://www.medica.be), I use a switch case to give a color to the navigation bar's active link.

I first declared an array `$case` with all the possible links in the navigation bar. Then, I check to see if it's a function clicked on one of the pages (if the query string isn't empty) *and* if it was put into the `$case` array (to keep from changing color when other links inside other pages are clicked.)

If true, `$current` will get a value like `docs_zamo` or `akuut_wgakuut --> FILENAME_QUERY.` I only want to change the color when I have declared it before (in the $case array)  Otherwise, it will just be the filename (without '.php')

I find this piece of code rather unwieldy. Is there another way to do the job? I'm pretty new to PHP. I thought; if there's a function checking whether a case exists inside a switch, then I wouldn't need the $case array, because I would've declared the existence of the link inside the switch case already.

**The code to check if it's a FILENAME_QUERY link:**

```
$case = array("index","medica","praesidium","akuut","sponsors","docs","docs_zamo","kalender","evenementen","fotos","werking","jaarraden","akuut_wgakuut","onderwijs","sociaal","sport","werkgroepen","eerstejaars","international",);

if (($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] != "") && (in_array(basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],'.php') ."_". str_replace('actie=','',$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']),$case) == true)) {
    $current = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],'.php') ."_". str_replace('actie=','',$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
}
else {$current = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],'.php');}
```

**The switch:**

```
$id = array("","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","");
switch($current)
{
    case $case[0]:$id[0]="class = 'here'";break;
    case $case[1]:$id[1]="class = 'here'";break;
    case $case[2]:$id[2]="class = 'here'";break;
    case $case[3]:$id[3]="class = 'here'";break;
    case $case[4]:$id[4]="class = 'here'";break;
    case $case[5]:$id[5]="class = 'here'";break;
    case $case[6]:$id[18]="class = 'here'";break;
    case $case[7]:$id[6]="class = 'here'";break;
    case $case[8]:$id[7]="class = 'here'";break;
    case $case[9]:$id[8]="class = 'here'";break;
    case $case[10]:$id[9]="class = 'here'";break;
    case $case[11]:$id[10]="class = 'here'";break;
    case $case[12]:$id[11]="class = 'here'";break;
    case $case[13]:$id[12]="class = 'here'";break;
    case $case[14]:$id[13]="class = 'here'";break;
    case $case[15]:$id[14]="class = 'here'";break;
    case $case[16]:$id[15]="class = 'here'";break;
    case $case[17]:$id[16]="class = 'here'";break;
    case $case[18]:$id[17]="class = 'here'";break;
}
?>
```

**The HTML:**

```
<div id='menu'>
        <ul>
            <li><a href='index.php' <? echo $id[0]; ?>>home</a></li>
            <li><a href='medica.php' <? echo $id[1]; ?>>medica</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href='praesidium.php' <? echo $id[2]; ?>>&raquo; praesidium</a></li>
                    <li><a href='akuut.php' <? echo $id[3]; ?>>&raquo; akuut</a></li>
                    <li><a href='sponsors.php' <? echo $id[4]; ?>>&raquo; sponsors</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href='docs.php' <? echo $id[5]; ?>>doc's bar</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href='docs.php' <? echo $id[5]; ?>>&raquo; doc's</a></li>
                    <li><a href='docs.php?actie=zamo' <? echo $id[18]; ?>>&raquo; zamo</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href='kalender.php' <? echo $id[6]; ?>>kalender</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href='evenementen.php' <? echo $id[7]; ?>>&raquo; evenementen</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href='fotos.php' <? echo $id[8]; ?>>foto's</a></li>
            <li><a href='werking.php' <? echo $id[9]; ?>>Werking</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href='jaarraden.php' <? echo $id[10]; ?>>&raquo; jaarraden</a></li>
                    <li><a href='akuut.php?actie=wgakuut' <? echo $id[11]; ?>>&raquo; akuut</a></li>
                    <li><a href='onderwijs.php' <? echo $id[12]; ?>>&raquo; onderwijs</a></li>
                    <li><a href='sociaal.php' <? echo $id[13]; ?>>&raquo; sociaal</a></li>
                    <li><a href='sport.php' <? echo $id[14]; ?>>&raquo; sport</a></li>
                    <li><a href='werkgroepen.php' <? echo $id[15]; ?>>&raquo; werkgroepen</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href='eerstejaars.php' <? echo $id[16]; ?>>eerstejaars</a></li>
            <li><a href='https://www.medica-csd.be' target='_blank'>cursusdienst</a></li>
            <li style='border:none;'><a href='http://www.medica.be/w' target='_blank'>wikimedica</a></li>
            <li><a href='international.php' <? echo $id[17]; ?>>international <img src='site/images/gb.png'></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: or can someone improve my code even though it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This entire block...

```
switch($current)
{
    case $case[0]:$id[0]="class = 'here'";break;
    case $case[1]:$id[1]="class = 'here'";break;
    case $case[2]:$id[2]="class = 'here'";break;
    case $case[3]:$id[3]="class = 'here'";break;
    case $case[4]:$id[4]="class = 'here'";break;
    case $case[5]:$id[5]="class = 'here'";break;
    case $case[6]:$id[18]="class = 'here'";break;
    case $case[7]:$id[6]="class = 'here'";break;
    case $case[8]:$id[7]="class = 'here'";break;
    case $case[9]:$id[8]="class = 'here'";break;
    case $case[10]:$id[9]="class = 'here'";break;
    case $case[11]:$id[10]="class = 'here'";break;
    case $case[12]:$id[11]="class = 'here'";break;
    case $case[13]:$id[12]="class = 'here'";break;
    case $case[14]:$id[13]="class = 'here'";break;
    case $case[15]:$id[14]="class = 'here'";break;
    case $case[16]:$id[15]="class = 'here'";break;
    case $case[17]:$id[16]="class = 'here'";break;
    case $case[18]:$id[17]="class = 'here'";break;
}
```

can be replaced with a loop:

```
for($i=0;$i<19;$i++) {
    if($case[$i] == $current) {
        $id[$i] = "class = 'here'";
        break;
    }
}
```

In general, if you find yourself writing nearly the same thing for multiple lines, you can probably replace it with a loop somehow (and almost certainly should).

Comment: what about     case $case[6]:$id[18]="class = 'here'";break; case in the original code ?

Comment: That's interesting, thanks! About $case[6]:$id[18] -> I could change the corresponnding place in the arrays :)

Comment: You got the loop code wrong, but I managed to resolve it :)

for($i=0;$i<19;$i++) {
    if($case[$i] == $current) {
        $id[$i] = "class = 'here'";
  break;
    }

Comment: Sorry, my mistake there. I've fixed it. :)