# Changing color on a href (switch class?)

Tags: php

So I am making a seat reservation system for a LAN party I and some friends are arranging and I have a problem when turning the reserved seats from green to red.
Here is all of the reservation system.

```
$id = isset($_GET["id"])  ? intval($_GET["id"]) : 0;
global $id;
$reserved = ($id == 0);
if(!empty($_POST))
{
   $firstName = $dbConn->real_escape_string($_POST["firstName"]);
   $isReserved = 1;
   //Database insert
$query = "UPDATE pbtest SET firstName ='$firstName', isReserved =    '$isReserved', liClass = '$liClass' WHERE id = $id";
query($query);
header("location: platsBokning.php");
die();

}
$query = "SELECT isReserved FROM pbtest WHERE id= $id ";
$result = query($query);
$formPreset = $result->fetch_assoc();

if($formPreset['isReserved'] == 1)
{
   die('Reserved');
}
else
{

}
   for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++)
{
    $id = $i;
    echo('<a href="platsBokning.php?id=' . $id . '" class="unoccupiedSeat"       id="' . $id . '" ></a>');
}
if(!$reserved)
{
?>
<div id="pbContent">
   <form method="post" action="" id="platsBokning"><div>
<?php
   createInput("firstName", "Förnamn", "text", "inputContainer1"); //input       function
   createSubmit("submit", "skicka"); //submit function
?>

</div></form>
<?php
}
?>
```

Does anyone have any idea on how this can be done?
Easiest way would be to switch class, but I have tried to do so for the past 2 hours with no result.
(Sorry for my English, Swedish dude here).

Comment: Hilsen.  Can you confirm that when you switch class the class actually changes?  If you inspect the element in the browser, has the class changed?

Comment: Yes it should do - then you have to set a css class for each state. Is there a corresponding occupiedseat class for unoccupiedSeat?

Comment: yes there is and it have a green background-color on it

Comment: Where is occupied or unoccupied actually set up? is it if($formPreset['isReserved'] == 1) { die('Reserved'); } else {

Comment: This might be useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17861158/easier-way-than-using-a-switch-case-to-change-color?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

To recycle my version you could use this - but Liam Wiltshire's version on the page I gave the link to is more elegant

```
  // set up the html clips
  if($formPreset['isReserved'] == 1){
  $html_clips = 'occupiedSeat'; 
  }else{
  $html_clips = 'unoccupiedSeat'; 
  }

  echo('<a href="platsBokning.php?id=' . $id . '" class="' . $html_clips . '"       id="' . $id . '" ></a>');
```

Reference similar question Using an if statement to switch class - a number of ways to do it on this page [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33714062/how-can-i-make-this-php-lines-sh‌​orter/33714159#33714159](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33714062/how-can-i-make-this-php-lines-sh%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Borter/33714159#33714159)

I prefer to keep the php calculations out of the html personally, and set up little slugs to drop into the html.

Maybe JavaScript might help

```
<script language="javascript">
documentGetElementById("<?php echo $id ?>").style.color = 'red';
</script>
```

Comment: It kind of worked but it gives all of the seats the occupiedClass, but if i go to a page like platsBokning.php?id=3 which is not reserved all the seats gets the unoccupiedSeat class.